# re-use google-places autocomplete input after page navigation

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-scope, google-places, replacewith

I need in a angularjs single page application a google-places autocomplete input, that shall run as a service and shall be initialized once at runtime. In case of navigation, the with goolge-places initialized element and the appropriate scope are destroyed.

---

I will re-use the places input field after navigate to the page containing the places autocomplete input field. With the method `element.replaceWith()` it works well.

---

**After replacing the element, I can not reset the input by the "reset" button. How can I bind the new generated scope to the "reset" button and the old scope variables. Because the old scope and elements are destroyed by the navigation event?**

```
    .factory('myService', function() {
  var gPlace;
  var s, e;
  var options = {
      types: [],
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}
  };  
    function init() {

  }
  function set(element, scope) {
    console.log('set');
    if (!gPlace) {
      e = element;
      gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

      google.maps.event.addListener(gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.place.chosenPlace = element.val();
          });
      });   
    } else {
      element.replaceWith(e);   
    }
  }
  init();
    return {
    'init':init,
    'set':set
  };
});
```

---

the navigation (element and scope destroying) will be simulated in this plunk by the `ng-if` directive that will be triggered by the "remove" button.

[see here plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/gIuxc9o4kvFgfvdeyLzC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can create a service that holds the last selected place and shares it among controllers and directives:

```
.service('myPlaceService', function(){
 var _place;

 this.setPlace = function(place){
  _place = place;
 }

 this.getPlace = function(){
  return _place;
 }

 return this;
});
```

Then create a **directive** that uses this service:

```
.directive('googlePlaces', function(myPlaceService) {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
   types: '=',
   options: '=',
   place: '=',
   reset: '='
  },
  template: '<div>' + 
   '<input id="gPlaces" type="text"> <button ng-click="resetPlace()">Reset</button>' +
   '</div>',
  link: function(scope, el, attr){
    var input = document.querySelector('#gPlaces');
    var jqEl = angular.element(input);
    var gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, scope.options || {});
    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.place.chosenPlace = jqEl.val();
          //Whenever place changes, update the service.
          //For a more robust solution you could emit an event using scope.$broadcast
          //then catch the event where updates are needed.
          //Alternatively you can $scope.$watch(myPlaceService.getPlace, function() {...})
          myPlaceService.setPlace(jqEl.val());
      });

    scope.reset = function(){
      scope.place.chosenPlace = null;
      jqEl.val("");
     }

    scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
     if(listener)
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
   });   
  }
 }
});
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
<google-places place="vm.place" options="vm.gPlacesOpts"/>
```

Where:

```
vm.gPlacesOpts = {types: [], componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}}
```

Comment: thanks for help, but i will not save the last place. I must re-use the places input without repeated initialisation each time.